# Clicking on an item automatically when I delete an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I need to add in this jQuery function that let when I click on an item and delete it automatically select next item and display it title and description in the card. If I click on the last item automatically select the previous item and display it title and description in the card

For example, I have 10 list items. If I click on the first item or any item between the first and last automatically select the next item of the deleted one and if I click list item 10 automatically select list Item 9.

```js
$("#btndelete").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".active").length) {
    $(".active").remove();
    var len = $("a").length;
    if (len == 0) {
      disabledButtons(true);
    } else {
      title.text("List Item none");
      description.text("Description none");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Click an item first!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 1">List Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 2">List Item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 3">List Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 4">List Item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 5">List Item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 6">List Item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 7">List Item 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 8">List Item 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 9">List Item 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 10">List Item 10</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card card-primary card-inverse">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title"><span class="result"> none</span></h4>
          <p class="card-description"><span class="result"> none</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnedit">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndelete">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndeleteall">DeleteAll</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery's index() methos to find the index of the active link:

```
var myIndex = $('.active').index();
```

This should be done before you delete it. Then you can set the new active link using this index, which does not change (the rest will move one index up when you delete one).

That should get you started.

Edit:

Set the new active:

```
$('a').get(myIndex).addClass('active');
```

Now you only need to figure out deleting the last item.

Comment: I try it but can you tell me what I need to do to make it work ?

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, mark it as answer by clicking the V sign.